# Spring Boot MVC(@WebMvcTest) test fails when all tests are running

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I am facing strange behavior while writing test cases for my project. Basically I have a basic spring boot mvc application with thymeleaf template.

And there is a controller which has file upload responsibility (this controller has also another responsibilities)

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/x")
@Validated
public class MyController extends MyBaseController {
  
    private final MyService myService;

    public MyController(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
    // ...

    @PostMapping("/y")
    public String fileUpload(@RequestParam(name = "photo")
                                     @EmptyOrAllowedFileExtension(values = {"img", "png"} MultipartFile photo,
                                     @ModelAttribute @Valid MyRequest myRequest,
                                 RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        String response = myService.doSmth(photo, myRequest);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(...);
        return "thymelaefLocation";
    }
}
```

Here is the `MyRequest`which is nothing but just simple record class:

```java
public record MyRequest(
        @OnlyPositiveValue
        long idOne,
        @OnlyPositiveValue
        long idTwo,
        @NotBlank(message = "32")
        @Size(max = 1024)
        String name,
        boolean deletePhoto
) {
}
```

This setup will run perfectly when I just run my spring boot mvc application.

Now here is the WebMvcTest:

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class)
class MyControllerTest extends MyBaseTestController {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private MyService myService;

    // Other test cases
    
    @Test
    void mytest() throws Exception {
        final String url = "x/y";
        Map<String, String> validParams = Map.of("idOne", "1",
                "idTwo", "1", "name", RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5),
                "deletePhoto", "false");

        when(myService.doSmth(any(MultipartFile.class), any(MyRequest.class)))
                .thenReturn(mockResponse());
        MockMultipartFile validFile = new MockMultipartFile(
                "photo",
                "photo.png",
                MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE,
                "test".getBytes());
        
        MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder multipartReq =
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart(url).file(validFile);
        validParams.forEach(multipartReq::param);
        multipartReq.with(csrf());                
        
        multipartReq.with(user(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5)));

        mockMvc.perform(multipartReq)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
        ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

If i only run the mytest, it works as expected, but if i run the all test cases inside `MyControllerTest`, then mytest fails. I could not find the acceptable reason!!!

Reason to fail when I run all test cases: **`name` is equal to null**: (but as you see in the code **name was not null**)

```java
Field error in object 'myObject' on field 'name': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.myObject.name,NotBlank.name,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [myObject.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name]]; default message [32]
```

Comment: Why does it fail? What is the error?

Comment: Hi @JoãoDias, I just added fail reason

Comment: And are you sure this is the test that is failing?